# PHP search for website with specific words

Tags: php, search

I'm trying to monitor a new products page of a website with specific words. I already have a basic script that searches for a single word using `file_get_contents();` however this is not effective.

Looking at the code they are in `<td>` tags within a `<table>`

How do I get PHP to search for the words no matter what order and get declaration they are in? e.g.

```
$searchTerm = "Orange Boots";
```

from:

```
<table>
   <td>Boots (RED)</td>
</table>
<table>
   <td>boots (ORANGE)</td>
</table>
<table>
   <td>Shirt (GREEN)</td>
</table>
```

Returns a match.

Sorry if its not clear, but I hope you understand

Comment: lol! why don't you do it on client side? Javascript style, then if you want to process it with php, just send it with ajax

Comment: Introducing DOM and Xpath! http://phpmaster.com/php-dom-using-xpath/

Comment: http://querypath.org Querypath is another option.

Comment: How about [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)? ;)

Comment: @DudeSolutions I will have a look into that, looks slighty over my head though.

Comment: @JosephGregory It's not beginner friendly by any stretch, but is the most reliable and robust solution for this kind of problem. Works even inside malformed HTML documents. BOSS!\

Comment: @DudeSolutions im using `$nodes = $xpath->query("//span[@class='newprodtext']");` to find all products but how do I make it only search specific words?

Answer (score 2):

you can do this like

```
$newcontent= (str_replace( 'Boots', '<span class="Red">Boots</span>',$cont));
```

and just write css for class red like you want to show the red color than `color:red;` and do same thing for rest

but the better approach will be DOM and Xpath

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to make a quick and dirty search over that HTML block, you can try a simple regular expression with the [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) function. For example, you can try:

```
$html_block    = get_file_contents(...);
$matches_found = preg_match_all('/(orange|boots|shirt)/i', $html_block, $matches);
```

`$matches_found` would be either 1 or 0, as an indication if a match was found or not. `$matches` would be populated with any matches in accordance.

Answer (score 1):

Use curl. It's much faster than filegetcontents(). Here's a starting point:

```
$target_url="http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/dom_nodes.asp";
 // make the cURL request to $target_url
$ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
$html= curl_exec($ch);
if (!$html) {exit;}
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

  $query = "(/html/body//tr)"; //this is where the search takes place

 $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
 $result = $xpath->query($query);

for ($i = 0; $i <$result->length; $i++) {
  $node = $result->item(0);
  echo "{$node->nodeName} - {$node->nodeValue}<br />";
}
```